# How to use SQL and PHP multiple criteria?

Tags: mysql, sql

If my original code like this

```
if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = 1;
} else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

if (!isset($_GET['urut'])) {
$urut =  "" ;
} else {
$urut = $_GET['urut'];
}
if($urut == 0){ $urutkan = "id DESC"; };
if($urut == 1){ $urutkan = "harga ASC"; };
if($urut == 2){ $urutkan = "harga DESC"; };

if (!isset($_GET['jenis'])) {
$jenis =  [] ;
} else {
$jenis = $_GET['jenis'];
}

if (!isset($_GET['kategori'])) {
$kategori =  [] ;
} else {
$kategori = $_GET['kategori'];
}

if (!isset($_GET['wilayah'])) {
$wilayah =  [];
} else {
$wilayah = $_GET['wilayah'];
}                           

$results_per_page =     10;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM item ";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);
$first_page = ($number_of_results/$number_of_results);
$last_page = $number_of_pages;
$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;
$previous   = ($page-1);
$next       = ($page+1);

$sql='SELECT * FROM item  LIMIT    ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page ;         
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

What is the right syntax if i want the output like this

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM item WHERE jenis LIKE '$jenis' AND kategori LIKE '$kategori' AND wilayah LIKE '$wilayah' ORDER BY '$urutkan' LIMIT ' . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page ;
```

Thx for help
...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score -1):

For use multiple criteria into MySQL query you have to use `AND` operator in query.
Below i give an sample to use criteria with `LIKE` clause.

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE jenis LIKE '%'.$jenis.'%' AND kategori LIKE '%'.$kategori.'%' AND wilayah LIKE '%'.$wilayah.'%' ORDER BY $urutkan
    LIMIT $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page
```